# Rails, override value ( or reset value before update)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a value in my model which is an array and I want to completely override it each time I save an edit.

Eks. 
Model [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

My edit form has checkboxes. So the next time I might just tick off on 2 and 4.

Updated should now be: 
Model [ 2, 4]

Right now it keeps adding the values to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I put this line inside my update method. Wasn't sure if that would ruin my new values in the beginning but it works perfectly.

```
@mymodel.value.clear
```